# Kivy: How to keep path updated from filechooser

Tags: python, kivy, filechooser

I have file chooser and I want to keep file path text input updated for reference. When user chooses file and clicks button the entire file path is taken by method.

How do I achivie the updated text input?

So far I have:

```
TextInput:
    id: file_path        
FileChooserIconView:
    id: filechooser
    on_selection: file_path.text = self.selection and self.selection[0] or self.path
    path: '.'
Button:
    id: save
    text: 'Save'
```

And then in .py

```
self.ids.save.bind(on_press=lambda x: self.save_file(self.ids.file_path.text))
```

- Problem 1.- Upon start the text input is empty - it should be filled with current viewed folder path
- Problem 2.- If I enter folder after start, the path does NOT get updated and stays blank.
- Problem 3.- After clicking file (which updates the file path correctly) and then clicking on folder the text input does NOT get updated.
- Problem 4.- I'm new in Python and Kivy and I have no idea why the hell is in [the example](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.filechooser.html) "and" & "or" - it doesn't to seems to be logical expression

  on_selection: text_input.text = self.selection and self.selection[0] or ''

The only thing that is said about selection is

> selection: Contains the list of files that are currently selected. selection is a read-only ListProperty and defaults to [].

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems I have to answer all my question on StackOverflow. Hope it helps someone in future.

.kv is missing **dirselect: True** this will place single-clicked folder to selection list. To enter that folder you have to now click twice.

The initial state uses **str(Path.home())**

The new way is:

.kv

```
TextInput:
    id: file_path
FileChooserIconView:
    id: filechooser
    on_selection: file_path.text = self.selection and self.selection[0]
    dirselect: True
```

.py

```
from pathlib import Path
class foo(Screen):
  def __init__(self):
    self.ids.file_path.text = str(Path.home())
    self.ids.filechooser.path = str(Path.home())
    self.ids.filechooser.filters = [lambda folder, filename: not filename.endswith('.sys')]
```

This solves the first 3 problems. About number 4 I'm not sure - I'm guessing it means
If there is any self.selection list use self.selection[0] but if there is no list, use empty string. Since selecting directory produces valid selection we don't need the other option after *or*

Feel free to correct my assumptions - I'd be happy to learn more.

Comment: The `and`/`or` expression in the example takes advantage of how python evaluates logical expressions. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations): "The expression x and y first evaluates x; if x is false, its value is returned; otherwise, y is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.". And in the same section: "Note that neither and nor or restrict the value and type they return to False and True, but rather return the last evaluated argument."